# How to filter out item based on properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i wanted to refactor code use filter instead of lodash _forEach , Below filter code is not returning expected response. any idea what is implemented wrong here ?

main.js

```js
const response = [];
const data = [{
    "isBrand": true,
    "drugName": "Lipitor",
    "specialtyPrice": {}
  },
  {
    "isBrand": false,
    "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
    "drugStrength": "80mg",
    "drugForm": "Tablet",
    "mailPrice": {
      "totalQuantity": 90,
      "rejectMessage": [{
        "settlementCode": "99",
        "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
      }]
    },
    "retailPrice": {
      "totalQuantity": 30,
      "rejectMessage": [{
        "settlementCode": "99",
        "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
      }]
    },
    "specialtyPrice": {}
  }
];
_.forEach(data, function(drug) {
  if (drug.retailPrice !== undefined || drug.mailPrice !== undefined) {
    response.push(drug);
  }
});

const filterItems = data.filter(item => item.retailPrice && item.mailPrice)

console.log(filterItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

expected result

```
[{
            "isBrand": false,
            "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
            "drugStrength": "80mg",
            "drugForm": "Tablet",
            "mailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 90,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "retailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 30,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "specialtyPrice": {}
        }
    ];
```

Comment: you changed `||` to `&&`. Additionally not every *falsy* value is `undefined`

Comment: this code works fine

Comment: I can't see any difference between the result and the desired result.

Comment: It's working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var objNotEmpty = function(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).length > 0;
 },
 objHasPrice = function(obj){
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("mailPrice") && obj.hasOwnProperty("retailPrice");
 };


const filterItems = data.filter( item => return objHasPrice(item) && objNotEmpty(item.mailPrice) && objNotEmpty(item.retailPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```
data.forEach(d => (d.retailPrice || d.mailPrice) ? response.push(d) : null)
```

So it would looks like this:

```js
const response = [];
const data = [{
    "isBrand": true,
    "drugName": "Lipitor",
    "specialtyPrice": {}
  },
  {
    "isBrand": false,
    "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
    "drugStrength": "80mg",
    "drugForm": "Tablet",
    "mailPrice": {
      "totalQuantity": 90,
      "rejectMessage": [{
        "settlementCode": "99",
        "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
      }]
    },
    "retailPrice": {
      "totalQuantity": 30,
      "rejectMessage": [{
        "settlementCode": "99",
        "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
      }]
    },
    "specialtyPrice": {}
  }
];

data.forEach(d => (d.retailPrice || d.mailPrice) ? response.push(d) : null)

const filterItems = data.filter(item => item.retailPrice && item.mailPrice)

console.log(filterItems);
```